# Is, וישע ויט ויבו from Exodus, the only three consecutive three verse that can be intersplayed a la the 72 Letter Name from Exodus

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

As is known, the three verses And the Cloud rolled.. And Moses raised His Hand... And the Pillar touched down between.. from Exodus.
Are intersplayed and that's what makes up the 72 Letter Name.
Like this
WYSAAMUDHANAN...
WYTMSHETYDO..  <--- spell this backwards
WYBOAMUDHESBYN...
And then reading down the columns and spell the 72 triplets. (Names?) Related new question

Question is is is this the only verses that can form this way for 72 triplets specifically and not other counts or patterns, but other patterns might be of interest.

Anywhere in Tanakh, but others and others might be of interest and be within the topic such as new ones like one I made up נוהי נהוע חושני. It's power is, Sacred Heart of Rabbi Nachman, Rabbi Nathan, feel our pain and pray for us, I offer my pain up into yours mine is then but nothing, Na Nach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, within Kabbalah there are other major names and combinations of letters that hold significance and are used for various purposes. One example is the 42-Letter Name of God, which is derived from a different arrangement of verses in the book of Exodus. This name is also considered to hold great power and is used in Kabbalistic meditation and prayer. Additionally, there are other names and combinations of letters that are studied and utilized within Kabbalistic traditions for different spiritual and mystical purposes. Each name or combination carries its own unique significance and symbolism within the Kabbalistic system.